# Calculating the number of space in each \t in C

Tags: c

I am working on the project that ask me to convert tab character to a number of space

For example,
fat\tcat
this is equivalent to 11 spaces. I have an input file that has 3 lines:

1. fat\tcat
2. hi\tgood\tbye
3. \t\toctopus

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
char arr[999];
int i=0;
int tab = 0;
int space = 0;

while (scanf("%c", &arr[i]) != EOF){

 if(arr[i] == '\t'){
   /*expression use to calculate the number of spaces 
 depend on the position of i*/
   /* tab = 8-(i%8);*/
   tab = ((i+8)/8)*8;
   space = tab - i;
/*printing number of space*/    
   printf("%*c", space, ' ');
 }else {
   printf("%c", arr[i]);
 }
 
 /*This block is for checking the next line reset i
  if hit new line => reset i to 0
  otherwise increase i by 1*/
 
 if(arr[i] == '\n'){
   i = 0 ; 
 }else{
   i++ ; 
 }
 

}
```

The output that I got is:
11 for the fat\tcat (which is true)
16 for hi\tgood\tbye (which supposed to be 19)

Comment: "*fat\tcat this is equivalent to 11 spaces*". It would help if you described why that string is 11 spaces. And how do you get 19 for `hi\tgood\tbye`. Just giving examples does not clearly tell us the rules. For example you have not even told us how many spaces a tab needs to be in your requirements.

Comment: @kaylum it does not have specific length, the project just say a tab character is between 1 to 8 space

Comment: Ok, but explain to us how you get 11 and 19 from those strings? If you don't clearly tell us the rules how can we know to convert from input to expected result?

Comment: @kaylum for example, fat\tcat, f a t will be the first 3 space, then \t is the forth space, as you can see in the code there is the equation. So i is the current position of \t (which is 4 in this case). So we have 4 + 8 = 12, 12/8 = 1 (int so it round to 1), then 1*8 = 8, but there is already 3 space from f a t, so I will need to print the remaining 5 space. Hope it's clear

Comment: "*in the code there is the equation*". Not it's not clear. The code has problems so why would I look at it for trying to understand what the correct behaviour needs to be? Don't you have the original problem statement that was given to you that you can share with us? "*So we have 4 + 8*" Where does the 8 come from? Please describe in words what the exact task requirements are. And please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71151600/edit) the post to update it rather than in comments.

Comment: @kaylum Here is the full description:
if a line consist of fat\tcat, it would print fat followed by five blanks then cat.
for the line hi\tgood\tbye, it should print hi, six blank spaces, good, four blanks spaces, then bye.
For the \t\toctopus, it should print sixteen spaces, then octopus

Comment: Each tab should get you to the next column that is a multiple of 8. So for example `fat\t` gets 5 spaces because it starts in column 3 after 'fat' (numbering from 0). 'hi\t' gets 6 spaces, and the following 'good\t' gets 4. So at each point where `\t` occurs you need to add `8-(column % 8)` spaces, where `column` is the column number where the `\t` is, numbered from 0.

Comment: @user207421 yes, I understand the algorithm, but I think something is wrong with my code

Comment: Well you've commented out the part that agrees with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a counting exercise. When looking at problems like this (where you are counting *spaces*) it is helpful to draw what you expect to see and observe the patterns. Here are your examples, using `•` for spaces.

```
fat•••••cat
└──────┘└──────┘

hi••••••good••••bye
└──────┘└──────┘└──────┘

••••••••••••••••octopus
└──────┘└──────┘└──────┘
```

The point of a tab character is to add spaces to add spaces until the number of characters output *so far* is a multiple of eight.

In order to do this you will need to iterate through your string, character by character, and keep a running total of how many characters you find. Every time you find a tab character you must modify the count to the next multiple of eight.

Comment: for some reason, I got the first one work, but the hi\tgood\tbye, it only printed the tab for the first tab (hi\tgood), but for the second tab it only printed 1 single space instead of 4

Is there something wrong with my code? Because I think I did exactly what you said

Comment: You have too many variables going on. You only need _one_: a count of number of characters output per line. Right now you have `i` and `tab`. When encountering a tab, output the difference between what you have already output and what the new count should be.